# download data from website when no URL specified

Tags: r, web, url

I am trying to pull related to trade (imports and exports) from different central banks or statistical offices' websites in RStudio.

This is not a problem when an URL link is associated to a file (.pdf, .csv, .xls, ...). However, I can't find a solution when the user has to manually specify manually the filters (e.g. years, months, sectors,...) and no URL link is associated with the query.

For example, I am trying to load the imports and exports of El Salvador at this url: `http://www.bcr.gob.sv/bcrsite/?cdr=38`

It appears that the data is not stored in the html code of the web page. I have tried web scraping, but the data cannot be found this way as the user has to first make a query and then click "Export the results".

How I can automatically load these datasets into RStudio?

Comment: It looks like the data needs to be queried on their website first, and then you can use the URL that Micha suggested.

If you want to automate this, and have no work done by the end user, I suggest looking into a web driver like [Selenium](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html).

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you need to use http://www.bcr.gob.sv/bcrsite/downloadsxls.php?exportCDR=1&cdr=38&xls=1 to get the XLS file which you can then parse. Make sure they are ok with this service being used as an API.